# PHP Array - Array Returns Value, And a 0

Tags: php, arrays

So I got this array:

```
$list = simplexml_load_file('http://feu01.ps4.update.playstation.net/update/ps4/list/eu/ps4-updatelist.xml');

if($list) {
    $data = array('firmware' => $list->region->system_pup[0]['label']);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And it outputs this:

> {"firmware":{"0":"5.01"}}

But there's also a zero there. How do I remove it from the array so it's like this:

> {"firmware":"5.01"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `SimpleXMLElement` result which you need to convert to a `string` if you want that data:

```
$data = array('firmware' => (string) $list->region->system_pup[0]['label']);
```

In JSON form it looks like an associative array, which it isn't, so the `[0]` trick which normally works to navigate to it won't.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note that using `var_dump` showed what this result actually was, so if you're ever stumped, try that first.

Comment: @FirstOne I think the `{'0'=>...}` stuff is just an ugly artifact of how `SimpleXMLElement` is implemented.